# How to save data in mysql using this?

Tags: javascript, mysql

/*In this i am calling this function using the onclick attribute and now i want that form data should be added to my sql database  */

```
   function home(){
            console.log('You have clicked on home');
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST","home.php",true);
            xhr.onload = function(){
                if(this.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }else{
                    console.error('some error occured');
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }
```

Comment: Have you written the query for adding the data to MySQL?

Comment: what does `home.php` contains? is this php script in your local project folder? check if it contains the SQL query that do the thing